# how to get a field from nested JSON in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, treeview

I want to take a field from nested JSON object as a string which is used as parameter.

I'm using a github project https://github.com/bencripps/react-redux-grid.

this react component is used for tree-grid.

I have a data and I want to map it as a tree-grid view.

My nested JSON object is below. It comes from an API. I want to take "**2020.total**" as a parameter (line 4)

```
 "id": 1,
 "parentId": -1,
 "Name": "Category 1",
 "2020": {total:120, tax:12},
 "children": [{
                "id": 11,
                "parentId": 1,
                "Name": "Category 11",
                "2020":  {total:23, tax:2},
               
            }]
```

when i finally get this parameter i use it as a variable in below code (line 16)

```
  const complexData = {
    showTreeRootNode: false,
    data:datafromAPI,
    gridType: 'tree',
    dragAndDrop: true,
    columns: [
        {
            name: 'Name',
            className: 'additional-class',
            dataIndex: 'Name',
            sortable: false,
            expandable: true
        },
        {
            name: 'Total Payment',
            dataIndex: 2020.total,
            sortable: false,
            className: 'additional-class'
        }],
    
};
```

"Name" attribute is working fine but "Total Payment" is not working.

i tried those syntax;

```
'2020.total'
'[2020].total'
'[2020][total]'
```

I know this is a little bit syntax question but i don't know how to search for it.

thanks for all answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = {
"id": 1,
"parentId": -1,
"Name": "Category 1",
"2020": {total:120, tax:12},
"children": [{
     "id": 11,
     "parentId": 1,
     "Name": "Category 11",
     "2020":  {total:23, tax:2},             
   }]
}
```

Try `a[2020].total`

Comment: thanks for answer, but there is no JSON obeject to attach a variable. there is a lot of nested obejct. I update the question.

Comment: @AhuraMazda but even if you receive data from an API, they are stored in a variable, not? What about `data:datafromAPI`?

Comment: ok, i use it as datafromAPI[2020].total what about children's 2020. it is not recognize total

Comment: Then you can use `datafromAPI.children[0]['2020'].total`. In your question you were asking about parameter from line 4, you didn't ask about children. It seems like your question is not complete, it's not clear what your end goal is.

Comment: it is not a one time operation. it is a loop. so i do not need only one nodes parameter. it should be reuseable variable. thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

You can access it like this:

```
let a = {
  "2020": {total:120, tax:12},
}

a[2020].total
a["2020"].total
```

Comment: Sorry, from where that 'a' come from?

Comment: Hey missed it, actually it was just an interpretation that we have the value in `a`, I have added the variable in answer

Comment: thanks for answer, but there is no JSON obeject to attach a variable. there is a lot of nested obejct. I update the question.